# Where is the type for onSelect's option type in antd Autocomplete?

Tags: typescript, antd

In our ui library we used antd AutoComplete and we pass onSelect function through.
OnSelect accepts 2 args. 1 is a value which is string and the other is option which shows type as OptionData | OptionGroupData

My question is where can I import OptionGroupData and OptionData from?
Version of antd:

```
"antd": "4.23.6"
```

PS: Module '"rc-select/lib/interface"' has no exported member 'OptionGroupData'.ts(2305)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the older versions Normally These interfaces were located in

```
node_modules/rc-select/lib/interface/index.d.ts
```

And they were:

```
export interface OptionCoreData {
    key?: Key;
    disabled?: boolean;
    value: Key;
    title?: string;
    className?: string;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
    label?: React.ReactNode;
    /** @deprecated Only works when use `children` as option data */
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}
export interface OptionData extends OptionCoreData {
    /** Save for customize data */
    [prop: string]: any;
}
export interface OptionGroupData {
    key?: Key;
    label?: React.ReactNode;
    options: OptionData[];
    className?: string;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
    /** Save for customize data */
    [prop: string]: any;
}
```

But in a version like "4.23.6", apparently these interfaces were removed. The second argument type is now:

```
{id:number; value:string}
```

For example you can use `AutoComplete`:

```
const MyAutoComplete: React.FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [options, setOptions] =
    useState<{ value: string, id: number }[]>([
      { id: 1, value: "firstItem" },
      { id: 2, value: "secondItem" }
    ]);

  const onSelected = (value: any, option: { id: number; value: string }) => {
    console.log(value, option);
  };

  const onChange = (data: string) => {
    setValue(data);
  };


  return (
    <AutoComplete
      options={options}
      onSelect={(value, option) => onSelected(value, option)}
    />
  );
};
```